# Ggplot Legends - Odd Issue

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

So I'm doing a plot in ggplot which is a combo of a bar graph and a line, and I want to add a legend. Everything that I've seen in the R Cookbook about legends in ggplot involve modifying the standard legend that rolls out when you do one type of plot through ggplot. 
Data:

```
x=c(0:10)
y1=c(0,.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5)
y2=append(c(1:5),c(6,8,10,12,14,16))
mydata=as.data.frame(cbind(x,y1,y2))
```

The call I'm doing right now is of the form:

```
ggplot(data=mydata)+geom_bar(aes(x=x,y=y1,col=c1),stat="identity") +
geom_line(aes(x=x,y=y2,col=c2,group=1))
```

I can totally do this as two charts, but I'd much rather do this with one. 
The issue is that the legend auto-generates when there's only one type of plot, but not if there are two types of plots. I was wondering if there was some way to have a legend with both types on there. Any ideas?

Comment: Not really sure what the issue is - could you provide some data for an example

Comment: The issue is that the legend auto-generates when there's only one type of plot, but not if there are two types of plots. I was wondering if there was some way to have a legend with both types on there. I've edited my question appropriately.

Comment: Can you re-create with `mtcars` or something if you can't post `mydata`?

Comment: you'll need to add `c1` and `c2`

Comment: i fabricated `c1` & `c2` and have a legend. i also think you meant `fill=` for the `geom_bar`

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1492)
mydata <- data.frame(x=c(0:10),
                     y1=c(0,.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5),
                     y2=c(1:5, c(6,8,10,12,14,16)),
                     c1=sample(1:4, 11, replace=TRUE),
                     c2=sample(letters[1:4], 11, replace=TRUE))

gg <- ggplot(data=mydata)
gg <- gg + geom_bar(aes(x=x, y=y1, fill=c1), stat="identity")
gg <- gg + geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y2, col=c2, group=1))
gg
```

works fine:

[image]

You've got the legend for all the mapped aesthetics.

Comment: Thats essentially what I have, except c1 and c2 are scalars, but there's no legend being generated. All I have is the line and the bar.

Comment: Have you quit R and/or RStudio and tried it? If that's not the issue, your code must be different in some way. Possibly using a `theme` setting somewhere you don't remember setting?

Comment: Nope, nothing. The command is `ggplot(data=tempp)+geom_bar(aes(x=Employees,y=PortionofClients), stat="identity",fill=3) + geom_line(aes(x=Employees,y=LTV.Share,group=1),size=1,col=2) +ylab("Portion")`, and it's not generating a legend. I think I'll do a double bar graph instead.

Comment: @riders994 that code isn't the same as that of the answer. It makes a big difference whether you specify `col=` inside the `aes()` or outside. Only attributes inside the `aes()` get legends and those values should be in your data.frame.

Comment: You should definitely read up on `aes` and `ggplot` a bit more as @MrFlick suggests. You'll only get a legend if you do `aes` mappings and you clearly are no t in your _"Nope , nothing"_ example.

Comment: The charts don't look the right way if I put the `col=` and `fill=` in the `aes()`, but thank you guys so much for your help.